# How to solve this boolean logic question?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Formalise the following argument in Boolean logic, and decide whether it is correct or not.
Explain your answer.

If the burglar is from France, then he is tall. If he is tall, then he came through the
window. The burglar is from France, or at least he spoke with a French accent.
If he spoke with a French accent and the evidence obtained is admissible, then he
came through the window. Therefore, the burglar came through the window.

Comment: In what sense does your source use "admissible?"

Comment: I don't know, he provides ambiguous questions with unambiguous answers

Comment: "Admissible evidence" is a legal term, which has little to do with soundness of deduction.  You can deduce that the burglar came through the window from the given claims by ignoring the "admissible evidence" bit.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I think the "and the evidence obtained is admissible" is just another statement. They may as well have said "and his hair is brown." Thus, we cannot conclude that he came through the window.

Comment: I thought that but apparently the argument is false, because you can contradict the logic statement.. I thought someone may have more expertise on this and maybe I am missing some theory, hopefully I can understand the future questions and pass the module

Comment: @user1688726 It is a logical possibility that he was not from france, he spoke with a french accent, the evidence was not admissible, and that he did not come in through the window.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  In that case, the best you can conclude is that if the evidence is admissible, then the burglar came through the window.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I think I understand the mechanics of the question now